# Can you grow a Giant Mushroom by planting a mushroom in the Giant Mushroom biome?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to grow a Giant Mushroom in the Giant Mushroom biome by planting it on the ground without BoneMeal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently no. But several people have asked for its implementation.

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/koayz/suggestion_mushrooms_planted_in_the_mushroom/)